# How do I set timeout for OkHttpClient?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am working on a native android project (Java) testing on a physical device with android 4.4.2. My OkHttpClient websocket connects but times out after 10 seconds, this is what I am trying to use to change the timeout setting.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setReadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but it is saying `Cannot resolve method setReadTimeout(int, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)`

These are my imports:

```
import android.util.Log;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.ws.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall;
import okhttp3.ws.WebSocketListener;
import okio.Buffer;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

and in my gradle file I have  `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

did you try with builder?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

**UPDATE**

try compiling  `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'`

Comment: I just tried them, same thing, `Cannot resolve method ... `

Comment: @CookieMonster try the updated answer

Comment: I added that to my gradle while keeping my old one and it doesn't seem to change anything. I tried removing my original one and keeping yours but I need my original for later parts where I use `WebSocketCall ws = WebSocketCall.create(...`

Comment: Are you sure you have your gradle setting working online ? i just tried with the okhttp ws library that you are using and i can access the methods for setting the timeouts with builder

Comment: @CookieMonster check my second update

Comment: @CookieMonster please notice that is not setReadTimeOut() is readTimeOut()

Comment: Oh I see, yeah that works, I was trying to add it to the wrong builder. I was trying to do:
`WebSocketCall ws = WebSocketCall.create(client,
                    new Request.Builder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .url(finalURL)
                            .addHeader("Cookie", tok)
                            .build());`

Comment: Workable answer guys. Thanks